# How do I get a specific file extension to behave as if .html in .vimrc file?

Tags: vim, macvim

I am using MacVim and have colours set on .html documents. I working on various projects that are using the Sparkview Engine for .Net MVC. These files end in .spark. How do I in my .vimrc file set the .spark extensions to map to .html so all my colourations appear on .spark files too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following in your `.vimrc`

`autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.spark set filetype=html`

It means that every time you open or create a new spark file, the file type is set to html for the current buffer. And the appropriate syntax highlighting should be applied.

Answer (score 4):

Use an autocommand:

```
    au BufNewFile,BufRead *.spark setfiletype html
```